# Struscture of MongoDB with too many collections

Tags: mongodb

I'm realy new in MongoDB and have a qustion.
I'm planing to build a base with too many collections (few hundreds). Each collection consist of documents with different strusture. For example collections have documents like this:

```
First Collection:
{ "name": "Tom", "surname": "Smith", "age": "37", "phone": "123"}

Second Collection:
{"company": "Example LTD", "phone":"456"}

Third Collection:
{"phone": "123", "email": "tom@example.com"}
```

I want to implement a search for a specific phone number across all collections. Does it make sense in terms of performance to create a metacollection that would contain all phone numbers from all collections? Like this:

```
Metacollection with phones:
{"123": ["First Collection", "Third Collection"]}
{"456": "Second Collection"}
```

I believe that searching the metacollection and then specific collections should be faster than searching hundreds of collections for a specific phone number. Is my guess correct?